# alias a table returning function (UNNEST) using pypika

Tags: amazon-athena, presto, trino, unnest, pypika

How can I write a query with pypika to generate the following SQL?

```sql
SELECT "x" FROM unnest(ARRAY[1,2,3]) as t("x")
```

The closest I can get to is this:

```python
from pypika import PostgreSQLQuery, Array, CustomFunction
   
unnest = CustomFunction('unnest', ['array'])
PostgreSQLQuery.from_(unnest(Array(1,2,3))).select('x')
```

Which outputs:

```sql
SELECT "x" FROM unnest(ARRAY[1,2,3])
```

But is obviously missing the required alias to allow me to use "x" in a following sub-query.

I am using Athena/Presto as the backend, but Postgres supports the same SQL

Comment: You can use SRF right in the `select` list: `SELECT unnest(ARRAY[1,2,3]);`. Regardless of whether it's there or in the `from` list, when left unaliased, the resulting column name will have the name of the function so I suspect `PostgreSQLQuery.from_(unnest(Array(1,2,3))).select('unnest')` could work.

Comment: _"I am using Athena/Presto as the backend, but Postgres supports the same SQL"_ - Trino (Presto) and PostgreSQL are different SQL dialects. Why not just use [trino-python-client](https://github.com/trinodb/trino-python-client)?

Comment: @GuruStron thank you for your solution. I will check out your trino suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [`Unnest` class from this comment @github](https://github.com/kayak/pypika/issues/550#issuecomment-1127442130) which hacks `AliasedQuery`:

```
from typing import Any
from pypika.queries import AliasedQuery, Selectable
from pypika.utils import format_quotes

class Unnest(AliasedQuery):

    def __init__(self, *selects: Selectable) -> None:
        super().__init__('t')
        self._selects = selects

    def as_(self, alias: str, *terms: str) -> "Selectable":
        self.alias = alias
        self.name = alias
        self._alias_terms = terms
        return self

    def get_sql(self, **kwargs: Any) -> str:
        unnest = "UNNEST({select})".format(
            select=", ".join(term.get_sql(**kwargs) for term in self._selects)
        )
        sql = unnest + self._as_select_sql(**kwargs)
        return sql

    def _as_select_sql(self, **kwargs: Any) -> str:
        quote_char = kwargs.get("quote_char")
        terms = ", ".join(format_quotes(term, quote_char)
                          for term in self._alias_terms)
        return " AS {alias}({terms})".format(
            alias=self.alias,
            terms=terms,
        )

    def __eq__(self, other: "Unnest") -> bool:
        return isinstance(other, Unnest) and self.alias == other.alias  # TODO

    def __hash__(self) -> int:
        return hash(str(self.alias))  # TODO
```

And your case can look like:

```py
unnest = Unnest(Array(1,2,3)).as_('t', 'column')
PostgreSQLQuery.from_(unnest).select('column')
```

Which generates:

```sql
SELECT "t"."column" FROM UNNEST(ARRAY[1,2,3]) AS t("column")
```

Which is executed fine by Presto/Trino. But I would argue that this a workaround at best.